# Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width suffers poor performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, graphics, printing

I have a function that prints to a DC.  I use `VisibleClipBounds` to determine the correct page dimensions.  This does, however, take a long time to run.

Simply writing out the `Width` or `Height` to the console takes over 100ms, and thats in release!  Can anyone suggest why it's taking so long?

```
function DrawToDC(Graphics dc))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dc.VisibleClipBounds.Width);
}
```